# Book Recommendation For Ordinary Differential Equation.

Tags: book-recommendation

I am doing my first course in Differential Equations and the book the instructor is teaching from is Arnold's *Ordinary Differential Equations*.

I like the geometric approach taken in the book but I don't like the way the material has been presented.

Can somebody please suggest me another introductory text on ordinary differential equations which takes a geometric approach?

Comment: Hmm. A [newer version](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1156266/11619) of this question has received answers. You decide which is a duplicate of which, if either.

Comment: I would recommend Ordinary Differential Equations by Morris Tenenbaum and Harry Polard
http://www.amazon.com/Ordinary-Differential-Equations-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486649407/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1426893070&sr=8-1&keywords=ordinary+differential+equations

Answer (score 1):

For my ODEs course, I used *Differential Equations with Boundary-Value Problems* by Dennis G. Zill and Warren S. Wright. The text inside is very good and clear. The material covered is vast and complete. The approach is not fundamentally geometric, but there is geometric interpretation in the explanations and many figures.

Here is a link to see what the book looks like:
[http://www.amazon.com/Differential-Equations-Boundary-Value-Textbooks-Available/dp/1111827060](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1111827060)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [the book by Chicone](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387307695), it is quite geometric and covers a whole lot of territory. I was a teaching assistant for a course based on this book.

That said, Arnold's book is a classic, and you might try reading this with that.