# Good book to study ODEs through geometric ideas

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, book-recommendation

When studying a subject, geometric intuition is important for me. The algebra books I know do not convey such intuition. Please recommend books on **ordinary differential equations** with an emphasis on geometric intuition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are books on abstract algebra and differential equations that give a lot of geometric intuition and motivation?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153290/what-are-books-on-abstract-algebra-and-differential-equations-that-give-a-lot-of)

Comment: Since you have posted a separate question on ODEs, maybe you could remove them from [your older question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153290/what-are-books-on-abstract-algebra-and-differential-equations-that-give-a-lot-of), so that the other question concentrates on algebra. (Then both questions will be more focused and this one cannot be closed as a duplicate of the other.)

Comment: Simmons has nice geometrical problems, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757007/best-book-for-differential-equations?lq=1

Answer (score 6):

Book: Lessons of Ordinary Differential Equations.

Author: Jorge Sotomayor (1979, IMPA).

Comment: Is there an english version of this book? So far I have just found it in portuguese.

Comment: I'm sorry, there is just in portuguese. But, I recommend for you the book: Ordinary Differential Equations, Perko, Springer or Ordinary Differential Equations, Arnold. Sorry again.

Answer (score 6):

A classic for this is Vladimir Arnold: *Ordinary Differential Equations*.

Comment: may i get the pdf copy of this..if so, kindly send me through daviddgl@yahoo.in@martin peters

Answer (score 1):

Differential Equations - Ross

you might get the pdf version in

www.bookfi.org