# Is there an English edition of Jorge Sotomayor's book on differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I am currently using Jorge Sotomayor's "Lições de equações diferenciais ordinárias", in Portuguese. However, Portuguese is not my best language by a long shot, and I struggle a little. Is there an English edition of this book?

I have tried looking in different sites, with no luck. The only possible mention is in another thread:

[Good book to study ODEs throgh geometric ideas](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1156266/good-book-to-study-differential-equations-throgh-geometric-ideas)

It's mentioned in the first comment with an English title:

- Jorge Sotomayor, Lessons of Ordinary Differential Equations, IMPA, 1979.

But I haven't been able to find it anywhere. The reason I need to use this book is because my college course follows it's material and it's presented a bit differently from the other books I have tried.

Comment: It would be a good idea to leave a comment on user [Oliveira](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/71356/oliveira)'s answer to ask directly if s/he knows of an English translation or just translated the title implicitly.

Comment: Good point. Done.

Comment: Similar book of Qualitative Theory of Differential Equations: https://www.amazon.com/Ordinary-Differential-Equations-Foundations-Communication/dp/3110115158#reader_3110115158

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of the books that started the collection "Projeto Euclides" at IMPA that has produced many first class books in Mathematics, to be used in Brazil. A link to the collection is here:

http://www.impa.br/opencms/pt/publicacoes/projeto_euclides/

There are NO translations to English or any other language for that matter, in fact, even the Portuguese edition is no longer available and out of print. Sotomayor has revised the book recently and we (I am the producer of the collection) are planning on bringing it back to print and may be even a translation to English some day!

Comment: What's the status w.r.t this?

Comment: The updated Portuguese edition is coming out this Fall, the plans for an English edition is still being hatched.

Comment: Is there any update concerning this?

Comment: @PauloNey how can I get the latest version?